# Unable to display image after using createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple ToDo app that adds a list dynamically.  When a specific string is entered as input, "party", then the expected outcome is to concatenate the image to the input string and display the image.

I have been trying to use several different examples of the createElement that I have found at W3Schools.com and other sites.  I have tried to specify the path to the picture as well as creating a variable for the image that I want to concatenate.  When I use console.log or console.dir the path looks correct.  The item is added to the ToDo list, but the image is not displayed and no errors appear in the console.

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
    
     $("#list-items").html(localStorage.getItem("listItems"));
    
     $(".add-items").submit(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    
    
     var item = $("#todo-list-item").val();
    /* When "party" is entered, do the following. 
    // Use createElement to dynamically add a picture to the ToDo List. */
    
    if(item == "party") {  
      alert("Time to party")
      
      var caddyshack = document.createElement("img");
          caddyshack.setAttribute("src", "assets/images/caddyshack.gif");
          caddyshack.setAttribute("width", "333");
          caddyshack.setAttribute("height", "250");
          caddyshack.setAttribute("alt", "Party Animal");                  
          console.log(caddyshack);
          console.dir(caddyshack);    
          //$("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" +  caddyshack  "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li");
          $("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item +  "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>") + "<img src=assets/images/caddyshack.gif' alt='Gopher' width='500' height='333'>"; 
            var x = document.getElementById("img");   
            function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementById("myImg").src;
                  document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = x;  
            }                                                                                                                                   
          console.log("img")
          $("#todo-list-item").val("");
       }  else if (item) {
          $("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");
        localStorage.setItem("listItems", $("#list-items").html());
        $("#todo-list-item").val(""); 
    } else {
        alert("You must enter an action"); 
    }
    });
```

```html
 <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Things I've Gotta Get Done</h1>
                <ul id="list-items">
                <!-- Here's where out todo list items will go! -->
                </ul>
                <form class="add-items">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-list-item" placeholder="What do you need to do today?">
                    <button class="add" type="submit">Add to List</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

The expected result should show the item and the image added to the webpage.  The verbiage is being added, but the image is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the script you shared the problem seems to be in

```
$("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>")+ "<img src=assets/images/caddyshack.gif' alt='Gopher' width='500' height='333'>";
```

It is due to the misplacement of the bracket before here `</li>")+ "<img src` the bracket of function closes here and after that you are trying to concatenate the `img` tag which will produce an error in the code.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

$("#list-items").html(localStorage.getItem("listItems"));

$(".add-items").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  var item = $("#todo-list-item").val();
  /* When "party" is entered, do the following. 
  // Use createElement to dynamically add a picture to the ToDo List. */

  if (item == "party") {
    alert("Time to party")

    var caddyshack = document.createElement("img");
    caddyshack.setAttribute("src", "assets/images/caddyshack.gif");
    caddyshack.setAttribute("width", "333");
    caddyshack.setAttribute("height", "250");
    caddyshack.setAttribute("alt", "Party Animal");
    console.log(caddyshack);
    console.dir(caddyshack);
    //$("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" +  caddyshack  "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li");
    $("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>" + "<img src=assets/images/caddyshack.gif' alt='Gopher' width='500' height='333'>");
    var x = document.getElementById("img");

    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myImg").src;
      document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = x;
    }
    console.log("img")
    $("#todo-list-item").val("");
  } else if (item) {
    $("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");
    localStorage.setItem("listItems", $("#list-items").html());
    $("#todo-list-item").val("");
  } else {
    alert("You must enter an action");
  }
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Things I've Gotta Get Done</h1>
    <ul id="list-items">
    <!-- Here's where out todo list items will go! -->
    </ul>
    <form class="add-items">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-list-item" placeholder="What do you need to do today?">
        <button class="add" type="submit">Add to List</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This explanation pinpointed the exact problem with the syntax and after modifying the .JS file
 the image is now being displayed correctly. Thanks so much for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You have a whole lot going on in that script that looks quite redundant. Here is an example of using native [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) with [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add content to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$("#list-items").html(localStorage.getItem("listItems"));

  $(".add-items").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  var item = $("#todo-list-item").val();
 /* When "party" is entered, do the following. 
 // Use createElement to dynamically add a picture to the ToDo List. */

  if(item == "party") {  
   alert("Time to party")
   const image = document.createElement("img")
   image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JCJ4.jpg?s=48&g=1"
   image.setAttribute("width", "100");
   image.setAttribute("height", "50");
      const li = document.createElement("li")
      li.innerHTML = "<input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item +  "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>"
      li.appendChild(image)
   $("#list-items").append(li);
   

   $("#todo-list-item").val("");
  }  else if (item) {
   $("#list-items").append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");
   //localStorage.setItem("listItems", $("#list-items").html());
   $("#todo-list-item").val(""); 
  } else {
   alert("You must enter an action"); 
  }
 })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Simple Todo List</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Things I've Gotta Get Done</h1>
            <ul id="list-items">
            <!-- Here's where out todo list items will go! -->
            </ul>
            <form class="add-items">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-list-item" placeholder="What do you need to do today?">
                <button class="add" type="submit">Add to List</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.  I am new to jQuery and Javascript and this approach to solving the problem was very creative.